# JSON Schema parser/validator with callbacks?

Tags: javascript, json, validation, parsing, jsonschema

What is a reliable JSON Schema validator in JavaScript that is extensible -- in the sense that there are hooks where you can add functionality as you parse elements?

Comment: What kind of extra functionality do you want?  For instance, `tv4` (disclaimer: my project) lets you define custom keywords (as well as custom formats etc.)

Comment: I need to store parts of JSON documents in a cache as I parse them. I was looking for a callback like onEachField(), as in the parser JULES from Ivartech. But I am also experimenting with tv4 because it is widely used.

Comment: OK - you're looking to load bits of the input data dynamically?  So you get some kind of callback when a given property is needed?  I'm happy to add features to tv4 where there's demand.

Comment: Yes, it seems like it would be very useful. I think there is a lot of support for this kind of thing in the XML world, as with SAX parsers, but not so much in the JSON world yet.

Comment: Cool - could you raise a GitHub issue?

Comment: @JamesMcCabe Hey, thanks for using looking into JULES! Never expected anyone would find it!

Answer (score 1):

[JJV](https://github.com/acornejo/jjv) allows you to add [custom checks](https://github.com/acornejo/jjv#custom-checks)

Perhaps something like this:

```
env.addCheck('cache', function (v, p) {
    if(p) { //you don't need the 'if' if you didn't want to.
        //your caching code goes here
        return true; //to make sure it doesn't invalidate the check
    }
});
```

The json schema snippet

```
firstname: {
            type: 'string',
            cache: true //could be anything if you didn't want the if(p) 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the WADL specification (http://wadl.java.net) and JSON schema specification (http://json-schema.org/examples.html).

Hope it helps.

Simone

Answer (score 1):

[FieldVal](http://www.fieldval.com) supports both synchronous and asynchronous validation (browser/Node.js etc.) with structured error reports. It provides a lot of common validation functions (i.e. email, dates, urls etc.) and allows adding custom functions.

Basic example of asynchronous validation can looks like this:

```
var params = {email: "email@example.com"}
var validator = new FieldVal(params);

//Email validation
validator.get_async("email", [BasicVal.email(), function(value, emit, callback) {  
    //Imitating asynchronous database call
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback({
            error: 1001,
            error_message: "Email already exists"
        })
    }, 5);
}]);

validator.end(function(error) {  
    if (error) {
        //Do something about the error
    } else {
        //Everything is valid - proceed
    }
});
```

Read our [blog post](http://www.minoblog.io/asynchronous-data-validation-with-fieldval-js/) for more advanced examples.

Disclaimer: I'm contributing to the project.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind giving JSON validator called JULES, that I've crated, a shot https://github.com/stamat/jules and tell me what you think. There is a way to extend the JSON Schema:

```
jules.validator.new_keyword = function(value, keyword, schema) {
    //define your validator here
    return true;
};
```